# IOS - XCODE - reverse IPA to Swift code

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have started building an iOS app using xcode and swift. During my developing work my HHD failed and I lost the project file and I have been left with just the ipa installed on my iPhone.

i was wondering if its possible to get the code back instead of starting everything again.

I have been looking online and I found that this may be possible using a jailbreak iPhone and gbd debugger.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to recover the code (no source code is in the app executable) but the other assets such as images can be. Even it the images were in an Asset catalog there are programs that can recover them.

Really, you need to use a backup, options include:

1. Get an external HD and use TimeMachine.
2. Use a remote repository such as Bitbucket or GitHub. The integration in Xcode is good.
3. Use an offsite backup service such as BackBlaze.

Keep in mind that data loss will occur periodically trough your career, start protecting yourself **today**. Tomorrow, whenever that might really be, will not be soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

Decompiling is a non-trivial task, and the code you might get will be far from what you put in. It also cannot recreate project files and structure etc. The time you will need to make a usable thing out of it (if even possible) will be tremendous.

Your best bet is to learn your lesson (i.e. backup, or even better with a remote git repository) and start over again. You won't be starting from scratch in your head, and the rewrite should get built quicker and cleaner.

Comment: Time machine is a good start, but really nothing beats an offsite backup (and you should be using source control tool anyway).